# How to Group by on the List<> property in LiteDB

Tags: litedb

I have following class where a `Post` can have many `tags`

```
public class Post
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public string Summary {get;set;}
  public List<string> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to get all the `Post`s grouped by `tag`s if the a tag has at least 10 `Post` associated with it.

Is it possible to do it efficiently in `LiteDB` with the current class? I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you need. But maybe your issue is than right now you have something like

`var posts = db.GetCollection<Post>("Post");`

Where var is of the type `LiteCollection<Post>`
and you cannot work with that.

You may use `.FindAll() or Find()` to get an IEnumerable and with that use `GroupBy` to group however you want. [1](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/669)

```
var groupedPost = posts.Find(p => p.Tags.Count > 10 ).GroupBy(*Group Condition*);
```